# eMMC spare capacity calculation

Tags: filesystems, flash, storage

I'm lead to believe that eMMC capacity is defined in the same way as other mass storage technologies, i.e. 32GB is 32,000,000,000 bytes.

The accessible address range of this 32GB device is 0:57,671,679, this multiplied by 512 gives the addressable capacity, 29,527,900,160.

This is a difference of 2,472,099,840 bytes.

Is this used as spare capacity which replaces pages which have failed?

Comment: Flash storage devices, just like disks, usually maintain a bad block table (but that requires a controller than can manage it) so the spare capacity *may* be used to replace blocks that have failed. This is usually system dependent.

Comment: Yes, the eMMC maintains a bad block table, however I'm surprised it retains 7.7% (2.3GB) of the device to supply this feature.

Comment: The actual capacity of the underlying NAND chip(s) is unknown to you, the enduser.  You cannot assume that the "32GB" means 32,000,000,000 bytes.  Manufacturers do round*up* capacity numbers.